# Gradle: using a directory variable

Tags: gradle

In gradle I want to use a directory variable, what in ant would be ${mydir}.

```
 def mydir = new File("mydir") 
  copy {
     from 'example.txt' 
     into '${mydir}/out/'
 }
```

How to do this? The docs don't contain information on this issue AFAICS, http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/working_with_files.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
into new File(mydir, out)
```

or if with `GString`

```
into "${mydir}/out/"
```

(note the double `"` quotes)